# Create a code to build a chatbot that is fluent in Persian

Tags: google-colaboratory

ک Create a code to build a chatbot that is fluent in Persian and can answer questions related to agriculture and sugarcane. You can use open source libraries like Hugging Face and Text Generator.

Use pre-trained models available in Hugging Face such as transformer models and customize them for Persian language. Then, train these models on data related to agriculture and sugarcane to create a suitable chatbot for answering questions in these areas.
Choose a pre-trained model like transformer models in Hugging Face.
Customize the model for the Persian language.
Train the model on data related to agriculture and sugarcane.
Create a user interface for interacting with the chatbot.

Comment: Do you have specific question related to this project? It's not clear what you expect to get out of this post.